# When i start tomcat in eclipse shows error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, server

When i start tomcat in eclipse indigo it shows below error.pls any one give solutions for this error...

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setRulesValidation(Z)V
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    ... 6 more'
```

Comment: Did you add/delete any jar or updated any jar in lib folder?

Comment: i did not any jar in lib folder..

Comment: Is the error occuring when you are trying to start tomcat for running app(project) ? Try to simply start tomcat without any app.

Comment: Without App its working fine. But with app does not start tomcat again showing error.

Comment: This means there is some jar dependency missing in tomcat lib which is required by your app.

Comment: Is the tomcat-util.jar in your lib directory?

Comment: Tomcat-util.jar not available in my lib directory..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where in server.xml was missing.

I tried adding the same but still didn,t work.

Later I found that the tomcat I have downloded was corrupt and didnt download properly.

So I downloaded the tomcat again, unzipped it and set the same proper configuration.

and It worked perfectly.

Comment: I noticed my server.xml was corrupt as well. I went and fixed the archive and reset my local tomcat and it worked.